# Grant Select, Insert, Update to a Tablespace

Tags: oracle, select, insert, sql-grant, tablespace

I've got a lot of tables in a tablespace, nearly 100. I have to grant Select, Insert, Update privileges on all those tables to a user. Is it possible? When I write:

```
GRANT USE OF TABLESPACE MYTABLESPACE TO USERNAME
```

I get oracle error "invalid or missing privilege"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the data dictionary view dba_tables (resp. all_tables, if you cannot access dba_tables):

```
declare
  l_SQL varchar2(4000);
begin
  for cur in (
    select * from dba_tables where tablespace_name = 'mytablespace')
  loop
    l_sql := 'grant select, insert, update on ' || cur.owner || '.' || cur.table_name || ' to myuser';
    --dbms_output.put_line(l_SQL || ';');
    execute immediate l_SQL;
  end loop;
end;
```

If you just want to generate a script, comment out the execute immediate and un-comment the dbms_output.

Answer (score 11):

`USE OF TABLESPACE` is not a documented option, where did you find that?

You can do this to allow a user to create objects in a tablespace:

```
alter user username quota [amount] on mytablespace;
```

To grant select, insert, update and delete on objects you have to run a separate `grant` command for each table:

```
grant select, insert, update, delete on mytable1 to username;
....
```